# Startup performance in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am having some performance problems when I am starting Jenkins inside Kubernetes cluster.

One of the points that sometimes occurs and it takes so much time is next operation:

`INFO: Finished Download metadata. 1,397 ms`

In this case, it is just 1 second but sometimes it takes like 40 seconds. I have tried to find this log message in Jenkins core but I have not found it, so I suspect it is some plugin. My question where is this happening, what is doing and why it is required.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked jenkins log file to see what it is doing?

Comment: Yeah I noticed this from Jenkins log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Feb 10, 2018 2:04:22 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Feb 10, 2018 2:04:22 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 4 ms
```

Believe you are referring to the logs like the one above. If yes, these are the log rotation strategy logs thats gets executed through AsyncPeriodicWork  class and it is configured in Jenkins specifically for discarding Old Builds.

Following image gives you the configuration in Jenkins UI

[image]

You can appropriately configure this based on your project requirements, if you feel this is impacting your startup time.